# Are there any workarounds for the lack of assignment operator overloading in c#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have a library that I'm trying to port to c# from c++. The library provides a class that's supposed to be a drop-in replacement for numeric types so that it can be used without substantially rewriting code. This is fairly trivial to do in c++ but I'm stuck on the lack of assignment operator overloading in c#. I want to have a class or struct that's something like:

```
public struct Number<T>
{
    private T value;
    private int importantInteger;

    public  Number(T initialValue, int initialInteger = 0)
    {
        value = initialValue;
        importantInteger = initialInteger;
    }

    public static implicit operator Number<T>(T initialValue)
    {
        return new Number<T> (initialValue);
    }

    public static implicit operator T(Number<T> number)
    {
        return number.value;
    }
    public override string ToString ()
    {
        return value.ToString() + "    " + importantInteger.ToString();
    }
}
```

but has a persistent memory of the value of `importantInteger` when it's updated. If I do:

```
var n = new Number<int>(23, 5);
n = 3*n;
Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
```

then I can see that `importantInteger` is equal to 0 because `n = 3*n;` is creating a new `Number<int>` object with the default value of `importantInteger`. I would prefer that the existing object have only `value` updated so that `importantInteger` remains unchanged, but at the very least I would like it to be copied over to the new object.

Is there any way to accomplish anything remotely like this? I've read through many similar questions and I'm well aware that I can't overload the assignment operator. Is there any elegant way to get similar behavior though? Do I really need to have the user do something like `n = Number<int>(3*n, n.importantInteger);` every single time they want to update it's value? This seems both inefficient and needlessly complicated/ugly for a user of the library. I'd really love to hear some viable alternatives that are idiomatic and more elegant.

Comment: You *couldn't* solve this problem by overloading the assignment operator.  By the time you're trying to assign the value the integer you're trying to use *has already been lost* when you converted the object into an `int` through the implicit operator.  The *only* way to solve the problem is to overload the `*` operator (or use a method instead of that operator).

Answer (score 1):

Why not overload the mathematical operators as well?

```
public static Number<T> operator*(Number<T> value, Number<T> otherValue)
{
    //Do your operation on otherValue here so that it is what you want
    return otherValue;
}
```

I am not exactly sure how your importantInteger would need to be calculated here, but if you have also created an implicit cast operator for `T` to `Number<T>`, this should work.

To follow up for your comment. Even though you can't use arithmatic operators on generics, you Could do something like this:

```
if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
{
    //cast values to ints and do the math.
}
else if(typeof(T) == typeof(double))
    //do double version
```

and so on. A little tedious, but it will get the job done.

Comment: I would absolutely love to do this but you can't use the algebraic operators with generics because there's no compile-time guarantee that they'll be available at run time. A type constraint for numerical generics would be hugely useful but is missing from c#. There are some very complicated workarounds but even with these it would still be very easy for a user to do a direct assignment like `n = 1;` and destroy the state.

Comment: @Ivanna If you must have those properties then you won't be able to use generics.  It's that simple.

Comment: @Servy It's kind of tangential to my original question, but this is what I was referring to: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: @Ivanna I just edited my answer to address how you could specifically handle this. A little tedious, but there aren't that many numeric types.

Comment: @pquest That still removes all static typing from the solution.  If static typing matters to you the only solution is to create a wrapper for every numeric type.